# hashCode can be the same for different instances of an inner class?

Tags: java

I have a custom `SwingWorker` inner class. I found several times their hashcode are the same for different instances of it. Why is that? Normal?

EDIT:

The inner class I have is a subclass of the `SwingWorker` class.

Comment: `SwingWorker` doesn't implement `hashCode` and therefore `Object`'s implementation is called. Read its javadoc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hash codes do not need to be different for different objects. The only requirement is that they must be the same for equal objects.

If it is a concern that your `SwingWorker` inner classes produce identical hash codes, you could override the `hashCode` method in your inner class to provide hash codes that suit your needs better. Of course you would need to override `equals` as well to supply the matching logic to both methods:

```
final int workerId = 123;
SwingWorker<String,Object> myWorker = new SwingWorker<String,Object> {
   @Override
   public String doInBackground() {
       ...
   }
   @Override
   protected void done() {
       ...
   }
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return workerId;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
       return other == this;
   }
}
```